# Devices can’t discover each other on same OpenVPN server

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, local, asuswrt

There are two devices, that need to discover each other in local network, but they’re in different places.
I have an ASUS router (RT-AC66U, firmware version
3.0.0.4.382_51641-g46d2311) that supports OpenVPN server installation. I’m out of NAT network, but my IP is not static, I fixed this by internal DDNS feature.
So I had set up DDNS, checked (control panel works fine outside of local network) it, had set up OpenVPN server, connected to it my device, all worked correctly. But the devices can’t discover each other.
What should I enable to make the OpenVPN Server to work like a local network?

*Settings are on the screen below; it shows that only one device connected, but second can connect fine, just I disconnected it for a while

Screen: https://ibb.co/nwNBR3m

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What discovery protocol is being used by those devices? Are those devices directly running their own OpenVPN clients, or relying on a router or something else?

Comment: @user1686 the discovery utility can’t be known, but all are using OpenVPN client that creates a VPN profile and installs it into OS. Don’t think that something is wrong with connection, maybe it’s a server trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Most "discovery" mechanisms rely either on multicast or broadcast packets. OpenVPN will only transport those when in "TAP" mode (Layer-2, Ethernet emulation).

Although the default "TUN" mode (Layer-3, IP point-to-point) is *kind of* capable of forwarding IP multicast or broadcast packets, the OpenVPN software will not actually do it.

TUN mode is also incapable of forwarding non-IP packets. Some discovery mechanisms work directly on top of raw Ethernet, without IP – this requires TAP mode as well.